# Is there a CDN service in Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud, cdn

In Bluemix, it used to have a CDN (Content Delivery System) Service inside catalog that we could use for cloud foundry applications.

According to its documentation, it is now deprecated and it will be off by the end of january, 2017. (https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/cdn/index.html)

Is there another service that can replace the old CDN service, and that can be used for Cloud Foundry applications?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Please see CDN Beta service retirement blog [1] for details. You can provision production version of CDN service now [2].

**Note:** The service requires paying account.

[1] https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2016/11/content-delivery-network-beta-retirement/

[2] https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/infrastructure/cdn/

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The CDN service you comment [2] is not available for cloud foundry apps. AFAIK, it's for infrastructure / VMs only. Isn't it? The "Create" button is not enabled for me. Another suggestion?